# Who are the brothers in Layton Brothers: Mystery Room?

Tags: layton-brothers-mystery-room

There is a mobile game in the *Professor Layton* series called *Layton Brothers: Mystery Room*. Why is it called like that?

Who are the "brothers"? The only Layton is the protagonist, Alfendi Layton, son of the main series protagonist, Hershel Layton.

Unless it refers to

> Alfendi's split personalities, Potty Prof and Placid Prof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to different theories, and also [Layton wikia](https://layton.fandom.com/wiki/Layton_Brothers:_Mystery_Room):

> Despite being titled "Layton Brothers", there's actually only one Layton in this game, and he is Hershel Layton's son

> The title appears to reference **Alfendi Layton's dissociative personalities**, as suggested by his reference to his "brother" in the first case.